# Screen very dim after resume from suspend

Tags: suspend, brightness, bodhi

I'm unable to resume from 'Suspend to RAM'. It resumes properly, albeit with a very very dim screen (so dim I can barely make out the desktop). Trying to brighten the screen using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys doesn't work, and the only option is to switch the machine off and on.

I'm running Bodhi Linux 2.3 with onboard Intel graphics. I think the driver being used is `i915`, according to `lsmod`, but I could be wrong.

Output of `uname -a` and `lsb-release -a`:

> Linux bodhiman 3.8.0-12-generic #21 SMP Tue Mar 12 17:39:30 CDT 2013 x86_64    86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Bodhi 2.3.0
> Release:        12.04
> Codename:       precise

What can I do to diagnose this and fix it?

Comment: Kernel version? There have been some issues with the more recent kernels and the backlight being set to zero on resume; not your issue, but possibly related.

Comment: Hello jasonwryan. I have updated the question to include that information.

Comment: You could try appending `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012' acpi_backlight=vendor splash` to your kernel line...

Comment: I tried that and it did not work I'm afraid. There must be another way..

Comment: I have the same problem with debian8 (kernel 3.16). I solved it running kernel 3.2

Answer (score 3):

I think I solved the problem.

@drs proposed I install xbacklight to make it work but after installing it, I kept getting an error message saying "No outputs have backlight property"

A little bit of googling the error led me to 2 files in the /sys/class/backlight directory. The 2 files were

`/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0`
`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight`

I tried,

`echo 5 | /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` and nothing changed

And then I tried,

`echo 5 | /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` and the screen went dark

So now I knew that I had to use the vendor driver (in this case intel) to change the brightness of the screen.

I opened /etc/default/grub and changed the line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor splash quiet"`

and then I ran the command

`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

and restarted the system.

Now my function keys to change the brightness are working and when I resume from 'suspend to RAM' it still resumes blank but now I can press the brightness keys just once to bring it back to pre-suspended brightness levels.

Comment: It's a minor detail, but are you sure that was `echo 5 | ...` and not `echo 5 > ...`? My /sys/class/backlight is empty, but I find it hard to believe that those files would be executables, plus the normal approach is to write something to the kernel control files in /proc and /sys to change a setting.

Comment: I don't have  linux box with me right now otherwise I would test it. But I believe you are right. Although I think "echo 5 |" works as well, even though it is slightly unconventional I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xbacklight` to set the brightness of your screen and you can place scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` so that they are executed when resuming.  Try creating this in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/99-set-backlight.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in 

    resume|thaw)

        export DISPLAY=:0
        xbacklight -set 60
esac
```

Make sure you have `xbacklight` installed and choose a comfortable brightness percentage for your screen.

Comment: xbacklight quits with "No outputs have backlight property". But googling the error led me to a solution. : ) Thank you.